# undefined reference to functions. linking error when pigpio is built with ROS

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, linker-errors, ros, undefined-reference

I'm unable to use pigpiod_if2 alongside with the catkin build since I keep getting linking errors while building as shown below

```
CMakeFiles/delete_me_node.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `pigpio_start'
main.cpp:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `pigpio_start'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `pigpio_stop'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `pigpio_stop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

below is the code that I used for identifying the problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pigpiod_if2.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "delete_me");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    int pi = pigpio_start(0, 0);
    int pi1 = pigpio_start(0, 0);
    int count = 0;
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        std_msgs::String msg;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "hello world "<< pi1 << count;
        msg.data = ss.str();
        ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());
        chatter_pub.publish(msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
        ++count;
    }
    pigpio_stop(pi);
    pigpio_stop(pi1);
    return 0;
}
```

and below is my `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(delete_me)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -lpthread -lpigpiod_if2"  ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )
```

What corrections do I make to my cmake file to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to follow [this link](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/util/Findpigpio.cmake):

```
add ${pigpio_INCLUDE_DIR} to "include_directories()"

add ${pigpio_LIBRARY} ${pigpiod_if_LIBRARY} ${pigpiod_if2_LIBRARY} to "target_link_libraries"
```